# Call function with param from JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

I hope you can help me.

I'm trying to call a php function from javascript.

when I place a value in concatenation with a string does not work but if I put a fixed value without concatenate if I called the function correctly.

I leave the code I use.

**Function from my controller:**

```
function size_make_dropdownlist($size_make_id)
{
    $output = "<select id='size_make' name='size_make' style='width:100px;'>";

    //$output .= $this->new_option('Seleccionar', '0', $size_make_id);

   // $query = $this->car_model->get_car_makes();

    $options = array('product_id' => id_clean($size_make_id));
    $Q = $this->db->getwhere('omc_product_sizes',$options);
    if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
    $query = $Q->row_array();   


    foreach ($query as $row)
    {
        $output .= "<option value=".$row['product_id'].">Talla ".$row['size']."</option>";
    }
    }
    $output .= "</select'>";

    return ($output);
}
```

**FUNCTION JAVASCRIPT**

```
function sizes(product){
var phpcodeis="<?php $size_make_dropdownlist=$this->MProducts->size_make_dropdownlist("+product+"); echo $size_make_dropdownlist; ?>";

//$size_make_dropdownlist=$this->MProducts->size_make_dropdownlist("+product+"); echo $size_make_dropdownlist; ?>"; //When use this line work perfectly but i need the another one

document.getElementById("php_code_size").innerHTML=phpcodeis;
alert(product);
}
```

**CODE HTML**

```
<a href="#"
   style="display:block; color:#333; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px;"
   onclick="sizes(1); return false;"> Sizes 1 </a>
<a href="#"
   style="display:block; color:#333; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px;"
   onclick="sizes(2); return false;"> Sizes 2 </a>
<span id="php_code_size"> </span>
```

or another way to do this?

I would understand a little more hope that this help me be a little easier.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You should take note that PHP is executed before JavaScript. In most scenarios, you cannot generate PHP with JavaScript and expect it to run (unless you're using JavaScript at the backend and have some magical bridge to PHP from it).

What you probably want is to make and XHR (AJAX) request from JavaScript and let a PHP service return pure data. JavaScript would then render the option elements from this data, ideally by using an HTML template engine.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ajax, barely with JavaScript, you enter their codes something that is similar to what I'm looking for.

To not take away much of his time.

I just need to fill a drop down link according to the press of the user.

Answer (score 1):

you can embed php tags in inline javascript but you can't do it in javascript files. you must either use ajax call to receive value from server. or embed the value in html file before the function definition (not very good approach!)

somewhere in  php file (in the head section of html for example)

EDIT:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myGlobalFromPHP = <?php echo myFunctionValue ?>;  // enclose it in quotes if it's a string.
</script>
</head>
```

Then in your javascript file you can use this `myGlobalFromPHP`

```
function(){
   alert(myGlobalFromPHP);
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ajax, barely with JavaScript, you enter their codes something that is similar to what I'm looking for.

To not take away much of his time.

I just need to fill a drop down link according to the press of the user.